# Откуда операторы берут номера 8 800

Tags: voip, телефония

Столкнулся с подключением номера 8 800 для офиса и стало интересно, откуда операторы их берут, а затем предоставляют абонентам?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, например, у **[РосСвязи](https://www.rossvyaz.ru/gosservice/gosuslugi/p329/)** можно взять.

Comment: Слишком лаконичный ответ, мало символов :)